# 'display: inline block' trick not working in firefox

Tags: html, css

what I am trying to create is a full page website (no scrollbar) with a block of text/images/divs that centres both vertically and horizontally. I have researched and used a technique using a 100% height div with 0px width and then a content div to vertically centre content. Works perfect in safari, not at all in firefox  (horizontal works in both browsers.) block of code used for this below...

html-

```
body

<div class="block">
  <div class="centered">
    ... content and images
  </div>
</div>
```

css-

```
html, body {height: 100%;}

.block {
background: url(images/bgimage.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover; 
min-height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
}

.block:before {
content: '';
display: inline-block;
height: 100%; 
vertical-align: middle;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}

.centered {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
padding:0px;
margin: 0px;
text-align: center;
*display:inline;
}
```

is there some equivalent to "display: inline-block" i can use for firefox? I can't use 'float:left' cause it won't vertically center the content div, and screws up the inline block statement.

All help welcome

- Cheers

Comment: mind providing a fiddlejs?

Comment: Your code doesn't produce centering on Firefox, nor Chrome, nor Safari. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eQDt8/)

Comment: i tried making a fiddle, but can't recreate the problem correctly

Comment: html, body {height: 100%;}

Comment: forgot to add that to the css

Comment: Still doesn't center anything ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eQDt8/1/)). Please make sure your problem is reproducible before posting a question.

Comment: The `display: inline-block` style has been around for quite some time, it's definitely supported in recent versions of Firefox. I don't remember the timeline from the top of my head, but it's possible that it has been supported as far back as the first version released.

Comment: i appreciate the help. I've heard conflicting things about inline block, I couldn't get it working but that definitely doesn't mean it doesn't. Managed to figure it out but I changed code to the one provided below, and with some tweaks it was fixed. Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the css rule below to your elements with inline style, it should fix it:

```
display: -moz-inline-stack;
```

Comment: tried that, apparently people say that only works with firefox 2, not any of the newer ones

Comment: Well test it with "BrowserStack" and see the result on different FireFox browsers. if didn't last one would be -moz-inline-box or -moz-inline-block, one of these should help.

Comment: still the same prob. everything gets pushed underneath the '.block:before' div. safari floats the div centred and beside it. Firefox puts it underneath.

Comment: i'd be happy to send you the files

Answer (score 0):

This is a working code which centers both vertically and horizontally in compliant browsers:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eQDt8/3/)

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.block {
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.block:after, .centered {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.block:after {
    content: '';
    height: 100%; 
}
```

Based on [Centering in the unknown](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/).

Comment: beautiful, fixed my prob, but added a new one, when the window scales down to a certain size the content shoots to the top. in safari

Comment: Nvm. I figured out a solution. I appreciate all the help. Saved me many hours of sleep. Cheers!

Comment: @user3550879 your *new issue* is usually an appreciated behavior cause the user will be able to scroll the content. Also mind sharing the way you did it?

Comment: basically when the screen was resized to the width of the content (whether with a specified width, or the width of the content) the content would go to the top of the page. I am going for a responsive site with a small content block in a full sized window. It would look bad if it was stuck all the way at the top. If I use a width that is a % of the width of the screen it keeps that from happening

Comment: @user3550879 The easiest way to fix that is `font-size: 0` to avoid spaces, and reset it to `.centered`. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eQDt8/4/)