# Display block-inline and max-width hides text on overflow in firefox, works fine in chrome

Tags: html, css

I have an element with some text title. It shows fine in chrome as below

[image]

But not visible in firefox as you can see below:
[image]

CSS settings i applied are

```
.editable-text-text
    {        
        display:inline-block;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        vertical-align:text-top;
        padding-right:20px;
        max-width:100%;
    }
```

If i make max-width:98% than i can see the text but then i loose text... behaviour. How do i achieve the
same result in firefox as i have in chrome.

html part uses aurelia framework.

```
<div class="editable-text-hitbox" if.bind="(!isEditing || !isEditable) && value">
        <div if.bind="contentType!='number'" class="editable-text-text" title="${value} ${unit}">
            ${value} ${unit}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi. Add html, pls.

Comment: added now, It uses aurelia framework but overall not much in html, just normal div.

Comment: Please don’t expect people to set up any specific frameworks, to be able to reproduce your problem. You have tagged this `html`, `css` only right now, so please present a [mre] of the issue that uses only those as well. (You can probably just copy the resulting HTML structure from the DOM inspector view in your browser.) What you have currently given us, on its own and without setting up any extra frameworks, does not reproduce the issue at all – https://jsfiddle.net/7somvrfy/

Comment: seems like it got fixed with  ```float: left; display: contents;```

Answer (score 0):

There are some answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23188764/display-inline-block-trick-not-working-in-firefox), one that uses `display: -moz-inline-stack;` and one that doesn't.

This [Mozilla blog post](https://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) has more on `display: -moz-inline-stack;`.